# JRuby dont finds Android Platforms

Tags: java, android, rubygems, jruby, ruboto

i'am creating a ruboto app with:

```
ruboto gen app --package org.ruboto.example.app_name --with-jruby
```

and i end up with this:

```
Could not find any Android platforms in C:\android\android-sdk/platforms
```

- Android platforms installed, also checked via android manager
- C:\android\android-sdk/platforms exists with multiple version folders
- Android is added to PATH
- JRuby Version 1.7.3 is fresh reinstalled

What iam missing?

Comment: Is the ANDROID_HOME environment variable defined?  Is it defined to c:\android\android-sdk ?  Then I suspect a backslash problem in Ruboto.

Comment: You should report this to the Ruboto issue tracker:  https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug in Ruboto 0.11.0 on Windows.  You should try Ruboto 0.12.0 and report the problem on the Ruboto issue tracker if the problem persists.

https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto/issues

Comment: I will test a newer version, thanks for working on this. I have seen your git issue related to the commits ;-)